# markdown table to html table converter in CentOS

Tags: centos, html, markdown

I am looking for a way to convert a markdown table into a html table using the shell.
I know this tool: https://linux.die.net/man/1/markdown
This does a great job and is exactly what I am looking for, but is unfortunately not available for CentOS or maybe I just did not find it.

Comment: This is kind of a tall order.  Have you started writing something yourself?

Comment: I could write somthing myself. But why if there is already a solution online somewhere that I did not find? I am not asking anyone to write a program for me. :)

Comment: Something like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47048906/8239155) or [this](https://gist.github.com/bsweger/177aa1b3214636862350)?

Comment: Yes this does the job thank you. I don't know why google did not show me those results

Comment: How about you use some python module : https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you just didn't find it, because it is disguised with the name "discount". You can download the source [from here](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) and build it by yourself, but there also seems to be a [CentOS package](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/discount-2.2.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html).